# query about Excel formula - function

Tags: excel-2010

I have an issue with excel, lets say someone purchased something in (A1)100 dollars and i have to cut (B1)4.5 % of the said amount as tax. then when i want to insert the remaining amount after the deduction of tax(C1) that is (A1)-(B1). it shows 96 dollars. but actually it should be 95 dollars.

Comment: Increase or decrease decimals, Excel may be doing a rounding and that's why you see a 96 instead of 95

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the cell that has the result (C1). Make sure it is number and has two decimal places.